# Run Software as Exclusive Shell Application?

Tags: windows, shell, operating-system

This has previously been asked (2001) but without a solution.

http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/58217-exclusive-shell-applications.html

In BPM Studio you have the option to run the software as an "Exclusive Shell Application". Immediately after logging into Windows, BPM Studio appears and nothing else Windows-related (taskbar, desktop icons etc) loads. On exiting BPM, the user is returned to the Windows login screen.

Does anyone know how this is achieved? I want to do something similar for some software i'm working on. I've done a lot of research and can't find any leads!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key in the registry is called:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon -> Shell
```

which should be set to explorer.exe. BPM Studio probably changed this key.

Comment: I marked an answer but forgot to mention 2 years ago but I tried this on Windows XP and have since used in Windows 7. It works fine. As an example set the Shell setting to "calc.exe"! You can also set the Shell setting for the current user instead of all users, so one user gets a custom shell and other users get full explorer etc. Thanks again for the solution and sorry for the delay in comment!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very much like a [custom shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms940134%28v=WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx).

All the MSDN documentation that I could find seems to concentrate on embedded versions of Windows where replacing the shell is clearly very common. However, I believe that the principles are much the same for desktop Windows.